# Restler2 passing random amount of parameters

Tags: php, api, rest, restler

I have problem in `Restler2` with passing parameters to function. In `Restler3` you can  pass parameters whatever you want like in this function

```
function sum()
{
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}
```

So for example url `http://...../math/sum/1/2/3/4/5/6` it will sum all the parameters, but in Restler2 this returns an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

. Do you guys know how to solve this?

Comment: Cant, because server has older php version, and we cant upgrade it at this time

Answer (score 1):

Restler 2 does not have that feature! Your best option is to add enough and more parameters to the function and then use `func_get_args()`

```
function($p1=null, $p2=null, $p3=null, $p4=null, $p6=null, $p7=null, $p8=null) {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}
```

Alternatively you can port the wildcard routes feature to restler 2 and we will gladly accept your pull request :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i know that i can add lots of arguments, but we need flexibility, We moved to Restler 3 for that. Thank you for answer  ;)